# How to create a readonly SpreadSheet Table in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp

Trying to present a table of data to the user, and I need to have sortable and resizable columns with the data set from DataSource.  Is there an example of how to do this somewhere?  Also need the function of doubletap on selectedItem to open a ContentDialog.

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: NuGet

```
Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid/
```

Step 2: XAML

```
<Page
    x:Class="App3.MainPage"
    ...
    xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls">

    <Grid>
        <controls:DataGrid 
          Name="A1DataGrid"
          GridLinesVisibility="All"
          AlternatingRowBackground="LightGray"
          CanUserReorderColumns="True" 
          CanUserResizeColumns="True"
          SelectionMode="Single"
        />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Step 3: Code

```
...
using Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp;

namespace App3
{
    // Table Row
    public class TStuff
    {
        public string LastName { get; set;}
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
    }

    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            A1DataGrid.ItemsSource = new List<TStuff>
            {
                new TStuff {FirstName="John",  LastName="Smith"},
                new TStuff {FirstName="Bob",   LastName="Spencer"},
                new TStuff {FirstName="Betty", LastName="Bennett"},
                new TStuff {FirstName="Max",   LastName="Harper"}
            };
        } // Constructor Method
    } // Class

}  // Namespace
```

If you need control over the columns in Step 2:

```
<controls:DataGrid 
          Name="A1DataGrid"
          GridLinesVisibility="All"
          AlternatingRowBackground="LightGray"
          CanUserReorderColumns="True" 
          CanUserResizeColumns="True"
          SelectionMode="Single"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False">  

    <controls:DataGrid.Columns>

        <controls:DataGridTextColumn 
            Header="First Name" 
            Width="SizeToCells"
            Binding="{Binding FirstName}" 
            FontSize="20" />

        <controls:DataGridTextColumn 
            Header="Last Name" 
            Width="SizeToCells"
            Binding="{Binding LastName}" 
            FontSize="20" />

    </controls:DataGrid.Columns>

</controls:DataGrid>
```

Comment: Hi @Bill Moore if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Answer (score 1):

There's the DataGrid XAML Control for UWP which is currently in pre-release, [DataGrid XAML control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/controls/datagrid) it is in pre-release as of this answer and is a port of the Silverlight version of this control but may be worth a look.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid/

Answer (score 0):

All of the use case described above can be handled by the Telerik "RadDataGrid" Control which is more robust than the out of the box grid view. It has also been opened source so there is no cost except if support is required.

**Company Website**
https://www.telerik.com/universal-windows-platform-ui/grid

**NuGet:**
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Telerik.UI.for.UniversalWindowsPlatform/

**Documentation:**
https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/universal-windows-platform/Introduction-uwp

**GitHub**
https://github.com/telerik/UI-For-UWP